# MySQL - conditionally add values from different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume 3 tables:

- Table 1 has information about a product's price (e.g. the base price)
- Table 2 has information about a product's additional price factors (e.g. taxes, discounts, etc.)
- Table 3 has flags indicating if Table 1 or Table 2 or both tables should be used in computing the product's total price

Is it possible in MySQL to compute the sum in this situation? If so, some guidance on the query would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure this could be done with a stored procedure, is that an option or do you need it to be a query?

Comment: Can you give us the table definitions?

Comment: Could you please post some examples (or the definition) for `Table 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE (SELECT flag FROM table3) 
           WHEN onlyTable1 THEN t1.col
           WHEN onlyTable2 THEN t2.col
           ELSE t1.col+t2.col END)

FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQL's `CASE` or `IF` for your purpose, for example something like this:

```
SELECT IF(c.flag = ?, a.price + b.taxes - b.discount, a.price)
FROM <Table 1> AS a
JOIN <Table 2> AS b ON <what ever>
JOIN <Table 3> AS c ON <what ever>
```

If I'd had the table definition, I'd be able to post a more concrete example. But, maybe, if you have a look at the documentation of `CASE` and `IF`, you could figure out your own solution.